# Matching a sequence of characters splitted by spaces after a prefix

Tags: c#, regex

### I have the following strings:

1. `-prefix <@141222969505480701>` where the second part e.g. `<@141222969505480701>` can be repeated unlimited times (only the numbers change).
2. `-prefix 141222969505480701` which should behave the same as above.
3. `-prefix 141222969505480701 <@141222969505480702>` which would still be able to repeat itself forever.

The last one should have groups containing `141222969505480701` and `141222969505480702`.

### So a few bits of information:

- The digit chains are always 18 in total so I use \d{18} in my regex
- I would like to have the numbers in groups for me to use them afterwards.

### What I tried

First of I tried to match the first of my example strings.
`-prefix(\s<@\d{18}>)\1*` which would match the entire string, but I would like to have the digits itself in its own group. Also this method only matches the same parts e.g. `<@141222969505480701> <@141222969505480701> <@141222969505480701>` would match, but any other number in between wouldn't match.

### What would sound logical in my head

`-prefix (\d{18})+` but it would only match the first one of the 'digit parts'.

While I was testing it on regex101 it told me the following:

> A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data.

I tried to adjust the regex to the following `-prefix ((\d{18})+)`, but with the same result.

Comment: The .NET regex engine captures *all* repeated groups, so that note is not relevent here. `-prefix(\s<@(?<digits>[0-9]{18})>)+` ... `match.Groups["digits"].Captures`. That should work for the first format you mentioned. (`\d` can match other digits, not just 0-9, by the way.)

Comment: That seems pretty good already, is there any way I can make the `<@` at the beginning and the `>` at the end optional?

Comment: Use could use three patterns with alternation: `(...|...|...)` with the three variations where the ellipses are. It's kludgy but it has worked for me with things about as simple as this.

Comment: This is another option: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html#delimiters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help to of @madreflection in the comments I was able to come up with this solution:

`-prefix([\s]*(<@|)(?<digits>[0-9]{18})>?)+`

Which is exactly what I needed, which even ignores spaces in between. Also with the use of `match.Groups["digits"].Captures` it made the whole story a lot easier.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will give a false positive on an input like `-prefix @141222969505480701>` (note the missing `<`).

Comment: Well the missing space is actually okay, but for the other stuff you are right, will update the answer in a moment.

Comment: @JorgeWanderSantanaUreña because I need to ensure that the other content does exist as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to list the 3 different allowed formats. In .NET it is supported to reuse the group name.

```
-prefix\s*(?:(?<digits>[0-9]{18})\s*<@(?<digits>[0-9]{18})>|(?<digits>[0-9]{18})|<@(?<digits>[0-9]{18}))
```

**Pattern parts**

- `-prefix\s*` Match literally followed by 0+ whitespace characters
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?<digits>[0-9]{18})\s*<@(?<digits>[0-9]{18})>` 2 named capturing groups which will match the digits
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<digits>[0-9]{18})` Named capturing group, match digits only
  - `|` Or
  - `<@(?<digits>[0-9]{18})` Named capturing group, match digits between brackets only
- `)`

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=-prefix%5cs*%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3cdigits%3e%5b0-9%5d%7b18%7d%29%5cs*%3c%40%28%3f%3cdigits%3e%5b0-9%5d%7b18%7d%29%3e%7c%28%3f%3cdigits%3e%5b0-9%5d%7b18%7d%29%7c%3c%40%28%3f%3cdigits%3e%5b0-9%5d%7b18%7d%29%29&i=-prefix+%3c%40141222969505480701%3e%0d%0a-prefix+141222969505480701%0d%0a-prefix+141222969505480701+%3c%40141222969505480702%3e)

[image]

You could also use 2 named capturing groups, 1 for each format. For example:

```
-prefix\s*(?:(?<digits>[0-9]{18})\s*<@(?<digitsBrackets>[0-9]{18})>|(?<digits>[0-9]{18})|<@(?<digitsBrackets>[0-9]{18}))
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=-prefix%5cs*%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3cdigits%3e%5b0-9%5d%7b18%7d%29%5cs*%3c%40%28%3f%3cdigitsBrackets%3e%5b0-9%5d%7b18%7d%29%3e%7c%28%3f%3cdigits%3e%5b0-9%5d%7b18%7d%29%7c%3c%40%28%3f%3cdigitsBrackets%3e%5b0-9%5d%7b18%7d%29%29&i=-prefix+%3c%40141222969505480701%3e%0d%0a-prefix+141222969505480701%0d%0a-prefix+141222969505480701+%3c%40141222969505480702%3e)